# How could I change my theme colors like this? (Pic below) or can I find a theme like this?

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, 12.04

[image: Like this]

I want my theme to look like this. How would I go about changing the colors to look like this or is there a theme that already looks like this that you? I am using Unity and Gnome Shell. Is there a theme for both those desktop environments? Is there an application for changing the colors? I'm using *Ubuntu 12.04 beta 1*.

Comment: And you found this where?

Comment: @UriHerrera I just found this picture and it looked cool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change theme colors there are three files you need to edit.

```
/usr/share/themes/{theme name}/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/usr/share/themes/{theme name}/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/usr/share/themes/{theme name}/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

In the beginning of these files you'll find 4 pairs of core foreground and background colors used in applications based on the gtk 2 and gtk 3 libraries. Pair base_color and text_color are used for the document or text entry portions of windows where bg_color and fg_color are are used for the windows area where icons and labels are displayed. Selected pair is for selected text and the tooltip pair is used for the tips that pop up when you hover over a button or link. These colors may be applied by applications with varying opacity or shadings. The color of text in buttons comes from the fg_color. These sets of labels appear in all three files so I've been changing all three to be the same for any label I change. Here's an example of what I changed in the gtk.css file in the Ambiance theme.

```
/* default color scheme */
@define-color bg_color #cdc3b8;
@define-color fg_color #262626;
@define-color base_color #accdff;
@define-color text_color #262626;
@define-color selected_bg_color #01b9fc;
@define-color selected_fg_color #ffffff;
@define-color tooltip_bg_color #A3D0FF;
@define-color tooltip_fg_color #023C79;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of themes like that in gnome-look.org, and the theme you're looking is here i believe: http://abhizweblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/gnome-3-themes-how-to-install-gnome-3.html

Comment: Wow thanks that was basically everything I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The above screen-shot is the default theme of  gnome 3.4

> The current version of GNOME shipping in Ubuntu 11.10 is 3.2 (except
>   Movie Player, which is currently running at version 3.0). GNOME 3.4
>   scheduled for release roughly one month before 12.04 is scheduled to
>   hit.
>
> Version 3.4 of GNOME promises to be an interesting release given all
>   of the potential changes currently earmarked for it.
>
> These include the idea of GNOME applications no longer relying on a
>   menu-bar, and instead taking a more elementary-like approach of fitting
>   everything possible into the UI and overflow into the GNOME-shell
>   AppMenu; there are new applications like Boxes (a virtualization
>   application); as well as various UI changes to well know programs.*

source [omg ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/precisely-what-gnome-version-will-be-in-ubuntu-12-04/) 
[image]

Links:

1. http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/gnome-components-version-clarifications.html
2. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/latest-gnome-3-nautilus-mock-ups-point-to-refined-look/
3. http://jeremy.bicha.net/2012/02/01/gnome-versions-for-ubuntu-1204/
4. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/precisely-what-gnome-version-will-be-in-ubuntu-12-04/
5. https://live.gnome.org/

Comment: Specifically, this the dark variant of the Adwaita theme that ships with GNOME Shell, and is used with certain applications (like GNOME Boxes as pictured above).